# Grub Customizer Messed Up Grub - How Reinstall Grub Properly?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-customizer

Grub Customizer messed up my Grub. I regret ever installing it. I purged Grub Customizer, but how do I reinstall Grub? Here is my story:

---

I had a dual-boot system, combining `Windows 11` and `Ubuntu 22.04` with Grub. At startup, Grub would show several entries, which I found a bit annoying. I just wanted two simple entries:

- Ubuntu
- Windows

So I installed Grub Customizer on Ubuntu and customized my boot window. Simply stated - I removed all the entries that puzzled me, just keeping one entry for Ubuntu and one for Windows.

I looked at it and was happy. Until now. Today, `Ubuntu 22.04` offered me an upgrade to `Ubuntu 23.10`. I accepted.

Now, my Grub boot window looks like this (without the numbers on the left):

```
1  Ubuntu
2  Advanced options for Ubuntu
3  Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi)
4  Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi, serial console)
5  Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)
6  Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)
7  UEFI Firmware Settings
```

I have two questions:

> QUESTION 1:
> There are now two entries to start `Windows 11`: line 5 and line 6. They are identical. Why is that entry duplicated? How can I get rid of this duplication?

> QUESTION 2:
> Can I change the order of the entries, without resorting to Grub Customizer? I also don't want to edit files that are not supposed to be edited (which could give problems when running another grub update in the future).

I already tried to re-install Grub, from within my Ubuntu. This is what happened:

````
```sh
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
Installing for x86_64-efi platform
Installation finished. No error reported.

$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-14-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI iimage: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found
```
I'm not sure if this re-installation of Grub succeeded or failed. It outputs `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux: 1: version_find_latest: not found` in the end, so I'm confused.
````

By the way, this is my grub version:

```sh
$ grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4
```

**EDIT 1**
I found some tutorials about how to re-install Grub from a live Linux USB-drive. However, the steps given are too complex (not detailed enough). They require a level of Linux knowledge I simply don't have at the moment.

**EDIT 2**
From the comments:

> [@guiverc] I'd check you've not done something risky to your system if the details in your question are correct; `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` does not currently offer an upgrade to `23.10`, only to `23.04` as per `changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release` (ie. lunar is the next release that is supported, thus where upgrade will currently go). Your details as outlined in the question highlight a potential problem in your system that I'd suggest exploring (or your question itself is missing facts)

I have no idea. All I know is that Ubuntu offered me this upgrade, and I went for it. Now I have this version running:

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic
```

Comment: The "Advanced Option for Ubuntu" allows you to boot Ubuntu using the last kernel. You need this in case an updated kernel breaks your Ubuntu in any way. I recommend you don't delete that grub option. I have no idea why grub shows two entries for Windows. As you know this is a question answer site. It works best if you ask one question at a time.

Comment: See [Is removing memtest entries from GRUB a bad idea?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312411/is-removing-memtest-entries-from-grub-a-bad-idea) for how to remove the Memory Test entries.

Comment: Thanks @user68186 - I trimmed my post to now show only two questions.

Comment: See [this question and its answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491726/dpkg-error-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-23-10) for the `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux` error.

Comment: The recommended way is to edit the file (make a backup copy, say `grub.working_original`) `/etc/default/grub` and then run `sudo update-grub`. This allows you to change some default options and it will not be undone by any future updates.

Comment: Grub-Customizer adds its own proxy files. With new grub install, you may have both grub & proxy files creating duplicate entries. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404445/grub-customizer-missing-from-ubuntu-22-04 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491726/dpkg-error-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-23-10 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491892/i-messed-up-my-grub-config  How are you getting grub 2.12? Current in 22.04 is 2.06.

Comment: I'd check you've not done something *risky* to your system if the details in your question are correct; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS does **not** currently offer an upgrade to 23.10, only to 23.04 as per https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release (ie. *lunar* is the next release that is supported, thus where upgrade will currently go). Your details as outlined in the question highlight a potential problem in your system that I'd suggest exploring (*or your question itself is missing facts*)

Comment: @user68186, thanks for the suggestion and the link to that other SO question. However, that SO question you linked to has several replies. Which one do you suggest to apply in my case?

Comment: @guiverc and oldfred - please check my latest **EDIT** in my original post.

Comment: I would try [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491726/dpkg-error-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-23-10/1494052#1494052) for the `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/linux` error, but i have no way of knowing if it will work or break your system even more.

Comment: It's *probable*, or my view actually, that you were running Ubuntu 23.04 (*not 22.04 LTS as you state*), as the upgrade path from 23.04 to 23.10 is open & thus supported; the upgrade direct from 22.04 to 23.10 won't be opened until **after** 23.04 reaches EOL which will make 23.10 the *next* release, thus 22.04 will then upgrade to 23.10 (this occurs late next month; Jan 2024). I suspect your question details are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks @guiverc - you may be right