# Grub error when updating after removal of Grub Customizer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, apt, grub2, dpkg

After updating to Ubuntu 23.10 the Grub Customizer stopped working and since I have heard bad things about it I decided to just remove it. I tried removing it and cleaning up duplicated menu items on Grub2 and now when I use sudo apt-get upgrade I receive the following error. I am still able to successfully boot into Ubuntu and Windows, but would like to get the error resolved and my bootloader cleaned up. Thanks in advance!

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gir1.2-mutter-13 libmutter-13-0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0
  mutter-common mutter-common-bin snapd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up grub-pc (2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2:
 grub2 depends on grub-pc (= 2.12~rc1-10ubuntu4); however:
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT: I have tried the provided answers with apt-get clean and apt-get install -f and continue to receive the same error.

Comment: /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new says there is a typo some where, so grub-update is not completed. I forgot an closing } in 40_custom and it said error was on last line when actually in the middle. It also can be in /etc/default/grub or any of the scripts that customizer changed.  If you have not done much editing of grub, you can just do a total reinstall to grub. You show grub-pc, that is for BIOS based systems, but since 2012 systems have been UEFI with gpt partitioning and grub-efi-amd64. So be sure to reinstall correct version of grub. `sudo grub-install` if in your install.

Comment: Running the grub installer again completes successfully without providing an option to choose a version. I still receive the same error when running apt-get upgrade.

Comment: Comments here may be helpful https://askubuntu.com/q/1495675/243321

Comment: Some recovery instructions here (untested by me) https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/faq-why-you-should-not-use-grub-customizer/37844

Comment: Total reinstall of grub should have replaced everything. But do you still have proxy scripts in /etc/grub.d?  This should show details. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ If running Boot-Repair for fix only use Advanced mode and choose total reinstall & new kernel to reset everything.

Comment: It's not that these comments are not helpful, but I'm not sure I have the time to go through it properly. Is there way to run the 23.10 upgrade again now that I've removed grub customizer?Or can someone give me a more step by step command to clean this up?